# Why couldn't Captain America jump out of the aircraft he was piloting over the Arctic?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-first-avenger

At the end of *Captain America: The First Avenger*, Steve Rogers famously gets frozen in ice as he deliberately crashes the plane he's piloting into the Arctic.

In *Captain America: Civil War*, there is a scene where Steve jumps out the plane without a parachute, which demonstrates he's able to survive the jump.

Why couldn't Steve jump out of the plane at the last minute, still letting it crash into the Arctic? He would presumably still be able to survive for some time and they may have been able to rescue him.

Comment: Well, they did rescue him, it just took a while...

Comment: If he had let go of the controls, the autopilot would have re-engaged

Comment: There's lots of _possible_ reasons: he didn't know at that point he'd survive the jump; he thought he'd have a better chance of being found in the plane; he expected the weapons to blow up when he crashed and preferred that to death by drowning...

Comment: “In Captain America: Civil War, there is a scene where Steve jumps out the plane without a parachute” — I think that’s at the start of _The Winter Soldier_.

Comment: “Why couldn't Steve jump out of the plane at the last minute” — he was on the radio to Peggy! One doesn’t simply hang up! Manners!